# set OutputStream for a process

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, output-buffering

Here is a snipped code of my problem:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    if (process.waitFor() != 0)
        throw new Exception("error");
    reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

The running process is producing a huge output. If i redirect the output to a file, the process terminates quicker then printing the output on screen (standard output).
I do not wish to redirect the output to a file, due to low performance of the disk, filesystem permission, etc..

When process.waitFor() is executed, Java is being blocked until the process (callee) is terminated, and that can take a long time. So in order to bypass this issue, I would like to redirect the process' standard output to reader's stream input (last line at the code). i.e., the callee should produce an output to a stream linked with the reader, instead to print the output on screen.

Hope I was clear enough. I wonder how may I do that? Any assistance will be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the output of the process, just redirect to the null device which is `> /dev/null` on Unix or `> NUL` on Windows. All the output will be discarded and you won't have to worry about file permissions, performance etc.

If you do care about the output, take a look at [this post](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) which shows you the right way of reading the stdout/stderr of a process using a `StreamGobbler`.

Comment: I really care about the output. I wish to collect the output and analyze it. Instead of producing the output to the disk, I'd like to link the output of the process to the BufferReader (write to memory).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. All the coder did is to spawn a thread which will handle the output, when no waiting for the spawned thread. That is indeed a workaround, but it is foolish. Is there now way to just link\redirect a process output to a BufferedReader's input?

Comment: If you don't want to use a thread, don't. The article does show you how to link `proc.getInputStream` to a `BufferedReader`. You need to call `readLine` to consume the output.

Comment: @SUB__0 you need to read the stream before calling `proc.waitFor()`. In your code, you are reading afterwards.

Comment: @dogbane, I need to analyze the process' output only when it terminates with return value of 0. If I will not call waitFor() how will I know the return value? The strangest thing is, that when directing the output to the disk, the output finishes quicker than to memory. At least it seems like it.

Comment: You can't wait for the process to terminate before reading its output because the process might never finish. The process writes to an OS buffer of limited size and you need to read it promptly because if the buffer gets full the process will block.

Comment: @dogbane. ohh thanks for the notice. Do you have any idea how may I handle the return value?

Comment: The best way is to read the stream, store it in memory and then call proc.waitFor() which will give you the exit code. If the code is zero, perform analysis on the stream you have just stored.

Comment: Let me see if I got you right: you are suggesting I will create the BufferedReader() and only after, I shall call waitFor(). This will make it possible for me to read from the BufferedReader, which will not block the process that writes to the buffer. But, in my case, I have to analyze the output with-respect-to the process' return value. What do you advise?

Comment: The steps would be: 1) create bufferedreader, 2) read stream and store contents, 3) call proc.waitFor to get exitStatus, 4) if exitStatus==0 analyse the stream you stored.

Comment: BAD IDEA! the output is around 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output *before* calling waitFor(). At the moment you are waiting for it to finish, which it can only do when it has finished producing output, which it can't do because you aren't reading the output, so its buffers are full and it is blocking.

Comment: Firstly, thank. But if I am doing do, is there any the reading from the buffer will be faster than the writing to it? Is there any possibility I will reach EOF before all the output is produced?

Comment: @SUB_0 both those questions are contradictions in terms. ImputStream.read() is specified to block if there is no input, and 'EOS before all the output is produced' is logically absurd.

Comment: I need to analyze the process' output only when it terminates with return value of 0. If I will not call waitFor() how will I know the return value? The strangest thing is, that when directing the output to the disk, the output finishes quicker than to memory. At least it seems like it.