# Text file is created when running code from the terminal, but not when running it in Java

Tags: java, linux

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(
      new FileOutputStream("/home/main/smt/output/out.txt")));

  try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "/home/main/smt/tools/moses-2010-08-13/moses/moses-cmd/src/moses " +
        "-f /home/main/smt/work/model/moses.ini " +
        "< /home/main/smt/work/corpus/dataset.en" );

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

the command

```
home/main/smt/tools/moses-2010-08-13/moses/moses-cmd/src/moses 
  -f /home/main/smt/work/model/moses.ini
  < /home/main/smt/work/corpus/dataset.en
  >/home/main/smt/output/out.txt
```

gets executed in terminal of Linux and `out.txt` is created.  But in java no `out.txt` is created.

`dataset.en` is the input file.  Using exe moses which is in `src` and `moses.ini` in model the content in dataset.en gets translated and saved in `out.txt`.
But here while running this code no `out.txt` is created. I removed saving output in a file from the command eventhough nothing gets displayed in the console. If i change  `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ls)` its working fine.

Comment: Redirection operators, like `<` and `>` are part of the shell, and cannot be used directly with `Runtime.exec()`.  See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185024/set-outputstream-for-a-process) for options

Answer (score 0):

Shell can interpret the redirection and arguments. You should instead try

String[] cmd = {"/bin/ksh", "-c", "yourcommand < infile"};

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);